# Ontology IRI or Version IRI of ontology should be used for import?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology

For example, my ontology have

```
ontology IRI: example.com/onto1
```

and

```
current version IRI: example.com/onto1/1.0
```

What IRI should I use to import this ontology to new one?

I read the sections

- 3.1 Ontology IRI and Version IRI
- 3.3 Versioning of OWL 2 Ontologies

Of https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-owl2-syntax-20091027 but have not yet grasped this issue.

And connected question: which URI should be specified as xmlns prefix in owl file in RDF/XML syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ontology IRI should be used to import an ontology when you do not care about the version - and you wish to use the latest version of an ontology. The version IRI will give you access to a specific version, if you, for example, need to refer to a particular state of the ontology (e.g., need to avoid the latest version because of undesired or erroneous inferences).

Comment: Thanks. I understand this, but question is how should I do from perspective of sustainable work of my new ontology?


From one point I should use specific version to make it works after new version come.


But from another point will be good to "auto-upgrade" to new ontology version, if it has backward compatibility ofcource.

Comment: Most of the ontologies I've seen in the wild have no version IRI - however, I think it needs to be a case by case choice. I would go for ontology IRI myself,

Comment: I recently emailed with one of the worlds most prominent experts in ontology engineering and she asserted that the matter of ontologies and version control is still an open problem. – Just to assert that the conflict described by @GeorgeNovik is still relevant. IMHO there should be a best practise consiting of a semantic versioning scheme (i.e. increase major release number when it backward compatibility is intentionally broken) and automatic integration tests.